# setup password less ssh between two accounts from third account

Tags: ssh

There are two unix accounts `A` and `B`. I want to configure password less ssh between these two accounts.This can be done without much pain but my problem is that there are mutiple accounts like `A` and `B` where  I have to the same thing.I also have one admin account `C` (not `root`). So,I was thinking if it is possible to setup password less ssh connection between `A` and `B` from account `C` so that I can write a script and run it from account `C` every time I want do similar activity for different accounts.

(Also ,all the accounts have the same password .)

Answer (score 1):

You need to, as user C, execute `sudo -u A ssh-keygen` this will result in two files being created `id_rsa` and `id_rsa.pub` in `~A/.ssh`.  You would then execute, as user C, `ssh B@remote-host 'cat >> ~B/.ssh/authorized_keys' < ~A/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`.
Of course `~A/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` needs to be readable by user C.